# Client side validation for my form, still asks the server when I click 'submit' and I get a 500 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, validation

I have a couple things going on right now.  I have a form that I am trying to do client side validation on, and it is working however, if I click submit with one of the fields not being valid, it will still send the information to the client which I don't want to do until all of the information is correct.

The other problem I am having is I keep getting a "http-status code 500" when I click the submit button, and the form will still work and send out email even though I am getting this 500 error(using fiddler2 it shows this, otherwise I wouldn't know).  Can anyone please tell me why this is, and how I can remedy it please.  Thank you guys.

Here is my form:

```
<div id="Contact">
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<%using (Html.BeginForm("SendContactMessage", "ContactUs", FormMethod.Post))
{%>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="900" height="100%"> 
<tr> 
<td id="body" class="Content"> 
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"> 
<tr> 
<td align="right" valign="middle"> 
<label for="name" id="name">First & Last Name</label><br> 
<label class="req">
            <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.ContactName)%>
            Required</label> 
</td> 
<td class="fieldareacontact"> 
<%= Html.TextBox("ContactName", Model.ContactName, new { id = "Name", title = "name", @class = "fieldscontact" })%>
</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td align="right" valign="middle"> 
<label>Email Address</label><br> 
<label class="req">
            <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.ContactEmail)%>
            Required
            </label> 
</td> 
<td class="fieldareacontact"> 
            <%= Html.TextBox("ContactEmail", Model.ContactEmail, new { id = "Email", title = "email", @class = "fieldscontact" })%>
</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td align="right" valign="top" style="padding-top: 15px"> 
<label>Whatcha' Got?</label> 
</td> 
<td class="fieldareacontact">
            <%= Html.TextArea("ContactCommentsOrQuestions", Model.ContactCommentsOrQuestions, new { Style = "width: 260px; height:150px", id = "CommentsOrQuestions", title = "comments", @class = "fieldscontact" })%> 
</td> 
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Contacterror")%>
            <% if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
                {%><br /><%} %>    
</tr> 

<tr> 
<td align="right" valign="top" style="padding-top: 15px"> 

</td> 
<td align="right" valign="top" style="padding-top: 15px"> 
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="button" /> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
    <%} %>
    </div>
```

Here are a couple of my controllers:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ContactUsViewModel model = new ContactUsViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult SendContactMessage(ContactUsViewModel model)
    {

        if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                // get contact configuration
                DoSendMessage(model);
                //return View(model);
                return View(new ContactUsViewModel());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO: log/notify error

                //while( ex != null ){
                //Response.Write( "<HR>" + ex.ToString() );
                //ex = ex.InnerException;
                //}

                ModelState.AddModelError("Contacterror", "An unexpected error occured, please contact the webmaster.");
                return View();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Contacterror", "Please correct the above with a \"*\".");
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

The DoSendMessage() just sends the email notifications, and I know that function works, since even with the 500 error, I still can somehow get emails.

Here is the 500 error:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

The view 'SendContactMessage' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:

~/Views/ContactUs/SendContactMessage.aspx

~/Views/ContactUs/SendContactMessage.ascx

~/Views/Shared/SendContactMessage.aspx

~/Views/Shared/SendContactMessage.ascx

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'SendContactMessage' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:

~/Views/ContactUs/SendContactMessage.aspx

~/Views/ContactUs/SendContactMessage.ascx

~/Views/Shared/SendContactMessage.aspx

~/Views/Shared/SendContactMessage.ascx

Why is it looking for a page, when I'm calling a method?  Please help, and thank you all in advance, I'm sorry if this is a novice question, but I wasn't able to find more resources on why I am having these errors.

Here is the DataAnnotation:

```
public class ContactUsViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //this is my own regular expression that I created
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\.a-zA-Z0-9_]*[@][.a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]([a-z]{2,4})$", ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }

    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string ContactCommentsOrQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `else` statement:

```
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Contacterror", "Please correct the above with a \"*\".");
        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that did take care of my 500 error that I was getting! :-)  Can you please explain why the submit button works if the fields are not valid?  Since the client side validation for the fields work.

Comment: I'm a little confused what your html looks like in your view, maybe edit your question with the correct markup.  Also make sure your view model has the correct data annotations over each property you want validated.  Lastly, confirm that you've included the following scripts in your master page or your view:  MicrosoftAjax.js, MicrosoftMvcAjax.js, MicrosoftMvcValidation.js

Comment: And please mark my response as the "answer" if it answers your question. :)

Comment: I have those scripts attached, and the client side validation does work for each field.  If a field is left blank or does not have a valid answer you will know before hitting the submit button.  I was just wondering how to make so you will not be able to have the submit button not call the server until the client side validation is all correct.  I added my view model with the DataAnnotation

Comment: I double checked everything, cant figure out why your form would submit if your client-side validation messages are firing.